# Redmine: issue custom field throws an error

Tags: redmine, issue-tracking

I've added custom field for Issue with `Link` type and configured URL template  (as described [here](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineCustomFields)):

[image]

I expect that user entered value as task ID will be formatted into template, but when I try to test it this not works:

[image]

I took a look into logs, but there is not so informative record:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `format_value' for #<IssueUpdateListener:0x0000000006cfbdd0> Did you mean?  format_date):

app/helpers/issues_helper.rb:494:in `show_detail'
app/helpers/issues_helper.rb:429:in `block in details_to_strings'
app/helpers/issues_helper.rb:415:in `each'
app/helpers/issues_helper.rb:415:in `details_to_strings'
plugins/flock_notifications/lib/issue_update_listener.rb:51:in `controller_issues_edit_after_save'
lib/redmine/hook.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in call_hook'
lib/redmine/hook.rb:63:in `each'
lib/redmine/hook.rb:63:in `block in call_hook'
lib/redmine/hook.rb:60:in `tap' lib/redmine/hook.rb:60:in `call_hook'
lib/redmine/hook.rb:93:in `call_hook'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:589:in `block in save_issue_with_child_records'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:575:in `save_issue_with_child_records'
app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:172:in `update'
lib/redmine/sudo_mode.rb:65:in `sudo_mode'
```

---

I guess, I'm working wrong with URL template or what?

Comment: That looks like a bug to me, feel free to report it on https://redmine.org/issues

Comment: @AleksandarPavić I don't registered there, could you report this yourself (as you involved one)?

Comment: On my 4.1 Redmine it works as expected. What's your version?

Comment: @AleksandarPavić could you provide your configuration screenshot? 4.1.1

Comment: Same as yours... I can test on 4.1.1 once I catch time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace indicates that the error is caused by your custom `flock_notifications` plugin. This plugin (or the version of the plugin you are using) might not be compatible with your version of Redmine.

You should contact the plugin author on their preferred communication channels with this report so that they might fix the plugin.